# ¿Cómo puedo ver qué archivos y directorios hay en mi carpeta actual usando Python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x

Estoy intentando hacer un simulador de bash (la terminal de linux) para Windows usando Python.

Estaba intentando implementar el comando "ls", para esto hice lo siguiente:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os
wt = True
while wt:
    cmd = str(raw_input("{}>".format(os.getcwd())))
    if cmd == "help":
        print('''de momento no pondré este comando porque el output es largo y hace dificil leer el codigo''')
    elif cmd == "clear":
        subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","cls"])
    elif cmd == "ls":
        subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","dir"])
```

la cosa es que siento que si me quedo usando el `subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","dir"])` me va a ser dificil implementar el uso de banderas en el comando, como por ejemplo `ls -l`.

¿Hay algún modo de ver qué archivos y directorios hay en mi carpeta actual usando Python?

Comment: Mirate la [documentación del módulo os](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html), donde tienes la función `listdir` y otras que seguro te serán útiles para tu objetivo.

Comment: Hola @abulafia esa es la solución así que mejor escríbelo en forma de respuesta y a lo mejor puedes poner un pequeño ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la lista de ficheros en una carpeta, tienes la función `os.listdir()` que te devuelve una lista con los nombres de cada uno de ellos. Por ejemplo:

```
import os
for fichero in os.listdir():
    print(fichero)
```

Para emular mejor el comportamiento de `ls` necesitarías saber detalles como el tamaño de cada fichero, la hora en que fue modificado, etc. Estos detalles puedes obtenerlos con la función `os.stat()` a la que le tienes que pasar el nombre del fichero. Lo que te devuelve es un objeto de tipo [`stat_result`](http://hcidev.cs.unb.ca/acpc-docs-2017/python3/library/os.html#os.stat_result), quizás difícil de interpretar si no tienes claro como funciona el sistema de archivos. Los campos más importantes con los que podrías quedarte son `st_size` (tamaño en bytes) y `st_ctime` (fecha de creación del fichero).

Mírate el módulo [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) donde podrás encontrar muchas más funciones que te permiten acceder a primitivas del sistema operativo, lo que sin duda te será de utilidad a la hora de interpretar un *shell*. También necesitarás conocer cómo python representa las fechas y horas (y cómo imprimirlas), lo que está documentado en el módulo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

A modo de ejemplo, una modificación del bucle anterior para que imprima también el tamaño de cada fichero y la fecha de creación, por orden alfabético de nombre de fichero:

```
for fichero in sorted(os.listdir()):
  stat = os.stat(fichero)
  fecha_creacion = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_ctime).strftime("%c")
  print("{:14} {:20} {}".format(stat.st_size, fecha_creacion, fichero))
```

Ejemplo de (parte de) la salida que produce:

> ```
>    1099016 Sat Mar 24 13:27:35 2018 bash
>      34888 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bunzip2
>      34888 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bzcat
>       2140 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bzcmp
>       2140 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bzdiff
>       3642 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bzegrep
>       4877 Sat Mar 24 13:28:22 2018 bzexe
> ```